# C++ Pattern for a list of objects to be played sequentially

Tags: c++, list, object, design-patterns

I am looking for a c++ pattern to do the following :

I have a list of "Exercise" objects to be played sequentially.

I need a main object which is able to call a method in the first object in the list.
When the method is done, the method of the next object in the list is called, and so on....

Is there a pattern to handle that ?

Comment: a `for` loop maybe ?

Comment: yes, but how an object can tell when his method is done and that it is time to go to the next object in the list ?

Comment: @stephone You need to get yourself a book.

Comment: @stephone when the method returns, it's done, is it not? Or is this question about multithreading?

Comment: Composite + Command pattern?

Comment: Assuming the objects are of the same data type, why not put them all in an array and iterate through/call the methods that way?

Comment: @user2079303 Yes, when the method returns, it's done. No, no multithreading

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be simple composition

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>


class Exercise {
    public:
      Exercise( const unsigned int id ) : id_{ id } {}

      void play()
      {
        std::cout << "Playing excercise #" << id_ << '\n';

        /* play logic */

        std::cout << "Excercise #" << id_ << " played\n";
      }

    private:
      unsigned int id_;
};

class ExerciseList {
  public:
    ExerciseList( std::initializer_list< Exercise > exercises ) : data_{ exercises } {}

    void play()
    {
      using std::placeholders::_1;
      std::for_each( std::begin( data_ ),
                     std::end( data_ ),
                     std::bind( &Exercise::play, _1 ) );
    }

  private:
    std::vector< Exercise > data_;
};


int main()
{
    ExerciseList exerciseList{ Exercise{ 2u },
                               Exercise{ 7u },
                               Exercise{ 11u },
                               Exercise{ 3u } };

    exerciseList.play();
}
```